# e-altrow change order angular ejs

Tags: angular, ejs, syncfusion

I want to change the default behavior of altrow ;
this code

```
.e-grid .e-altrow{
background-color: #d1d8e2;
}
```

Instead of
white
grey
white

I want to have
grey
white
grey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query we have applied the row, altrow background color in grey white grey order using CSS property.

Please refer to the below code example and sample for more information.

```
.e-grid .e-row {
    background-color: #d1d8e2;
  }
  .e-grid .e-row.e-altrow {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
```

Sample link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eclsie?file=index.html

Comment: This solution only works globally, when style .e-row is defined in index.html or in styles.css
It does not work when .e-row is defined locally in component.css